# Why is called Mostowski’s Collapsing Theorem?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Mostowski’s Collapse Theorem (lemma) states that any well-founded and extensional relation $E$ on partially ordered class $P$ is isomorphic to a transitive class and $\in$.

My question is that why it is called collapse theorem because the content seems have nothing to do with collapse.

Comment: You "collapse" the relation $E$ to the standard membership relation  $\in$

Comment: A remark: You need $E$ to be set-like as well. Otherwise I don't see how to prove this in $\mathrm{ZFC}$.

Comment: @Stefan: Because that would be false without this assumption. Consider the relation $<'$ on the ordinals where all the ordinals are smaller than $0$, and otherwise comparison as usual.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You can still do it in second order $\mathrm{ZFC}$, right?

Comment: @Stefan: Same example.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're right, of course. I was thinking of a worldly cardinal $\kappa$ and $E \subseteq V_{\kappa}$. In this case we get Mostowski's collapse for non-set like $E$ (as viewed in $V_{\kappa}$) as well but the resulting collapse is not a subset of $V_{\kappa}$. My mistake.

Comment: @Stefan: Worldly cardinals are $\beth$-fixed points. So what you wrote makes no sense...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is instructive to think about the collapse of a set of ordinals.

Suppose that $A$ is some set of ordinals, its collapse is its order type. Why? We map the least element of $A$ to $0$, and then the next one to $1$, and so on.

In the general case, this might be a bit harder to visualize, but we sort of collapse the ranks of the members of the class to their "correct value".

Comment: No... when you apply it to a transitive class, it's not moved. You can't collapse what is already solid.

Comment: It *can be*. Just look at $\{\omega\}$. What is it collapsed to?

Comment: I think it is much better if you try to do it yourself.